# Can't get all files to link in pyinstaller

Tags: python, windows, distribution, paramiko, pyinstaller

sorry I know this is probably a noob question, but I'm fairly familiar with Python, but not with any type of distribution methods. I'm trying to package up/create an exe for a python program that I made that connects to an SSH server and uploads some files. I develop in Ubuntu, but I plan on giving it to friends using windows.

Ok so here we go.

I'm using the modulues:
os, sys, platform, tkMessageBox, webbrowser, re, Tkinter,tkFileDialog, and paramiko

In my directory called App I have the following files: 

text1.txt, text2.txt, text3.txt, app.py, script.sh, and all of the modules

After just running `python pyinstaller.py app.py` this is what my spec file looks like

```
# -*- mode: python -*-  
a = Analysis(['app.py'],  
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Ben\\pyinstaller\\pyinstaller-2.0'],  
             hiddenimports=[],  
             hookspath=None)  
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)  
exe = EXE(pyz,  
          a.scripts,  
          exclude_binaries=1,  
          name=os.path.join('build\\pyi.win32\\app', 'app.exe'),  
          debug=False,  
          strip=None,  
          upx=True,  
          console=False )  
coll = COLLECT(exe,  
               a.binaries,  
               a.zipfiles,  
               a.datas,  
               strip=None,  
               upx=True,  
               name=os.path.join('dist', 'app'))  
app = BUNDLE(coll,  
             name=os.path.join('dist', 'app.app'))
```

I was just wondering how do I get all my files to get linked into the exe. Because it runs the gui, but non of the functionality works. Should I zip all the files at the end and distribute that?? I'm new to the whole distribution thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line after the a.scripts, line

```
Tree('your\\path\\here'),
```

I know it works if creating a single file executable. Not sure about others though.
Make sure that the path is the path to the folder with all the text files, not to the text files themselves.

Comment: Ahhh ok yes I just want one excutable. Let me give it a try

Comment: If you want to create 1 executable, try something like [this](http://pastebin.com/bp827gkD)